# How to convert binary encoded data into file

Tags: php, zip, binary-data

I got a Mtom file from server where the file is in binary encoded form, I have extracted the data from the Mtom file but unable to convert it from binary to zip file.

This is a Mtom Data

```
----MIME_boundary
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Id: <start.xml>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include">
  <soap:Body>
    <TESTDOC>
      <TESTNET_INFO uniQueId="008P5PS">
        <ATTACHMENTS>
          <ATTACHMENT href="cid:34343@test.com" />
        </ATTACHMENTS>
      </TESTNET_INFO >
    </TESTDOC>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
----MIME_boundary
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="TEST.ZIP"
Content-Id: <34343@test.com>

PK    à6vV™žÃ+  ×  
   TESTDOC.XML]Q]kƒ@|n¡ÿázïÆ¯BÐñs'ñ
-!ÈU¯EðÎ ghÿ}OÅämw˜Ùuv?¼ÖvU#\h®˜(š²ß.|#‘¶»×§GçÝóI€}U06($yŒ"dKEG
©âÒ…†±I×iG¦âú‘NòÇˆdWô ¤üìBË°lÍ°5Ë"Æzûbnmù{f.ôûN6”MÑs&$hYÁª
+!øªj&(W¥—äÄÛ¯Ò š—
&áàÿ êç£xÄ;ÆB²VÐÊO§%[Ÿés³ï|Ü-:Ñ}ÏyÁ~!i˜á(ÁÙB} '5­8êù'kÕÑH¥¡BQ±@ýßô^ÂÑ'ýÉyøÒPK    à6vVLè×»  Î      INTERNAL_TAM.PDF…˜uT\Û²¯Á!¸kãÞt7îÖHãî!X»K€àœàÁÁ5x ¸
î}yûÝwïwïqÎ«æªQs®5_ÕœÅ¬•çù±˜76Ç§±ø €³…–˜
ÜÉÆÃ â‘G8xÀÝxäÌ=àP¸¥³\BÂÝÃ
nîˆåó>'ÝØyA‘x`õ}ÛœN
ÁûmÙ2W)å@€ð­V¾–~ŒN‹µ’ÉoG¢,çU^´…ƒÞ+=E³ç;;O-·7ÆÖ$`BÖÐªY—ÎûŸ<0¡€SæÖµ½Wê¯V«
¯'›ã’úV Â¬‰Àv©ÌwQ¼0þèù*‰)’_î.êê~^ÜÅŸ˜Xtuëï]¶kn‰\Úú?–¢“Pñ¬£†ÄfœÑ÷V¹¬NÛåü¬P<?ƒ±€ÙðÂV¾¸9ÆFik0¢‘ã‘éíGêC{¦lGˆëÅ9ù¤5÷§^(b.$¼ë.Óí%§9ù5LÒW­˜$,Ýo Üš^ÔÉ^àáãAëEÁDÜíRÞ6Û/òÕ˜:ÿ
\·öÜ´ÕcD%¶çà‚Šˆô—]«¶{ª^‹iŒJË3d28¦èg ¾¬ú‚ÕW€Îmãýãé&Q¥Ë•´»ZË$Õ9_-ëKIÌxºTbI-¨Õ4¥k¡èÓ)ÐÇ®s1Y3Nœjid4L°[

}Ÿ´É:èÓœ¨$“Â^\W¤oàbŸ†ÊÂ6i¦X>¶ºXuÇeCÎ®&àQÄ¯5î"üCR«ûûÇaÊø eó±f®pŠÍ:Œ]¤Qfq4 j@§¤(ŸÉô\Gïû¡Ëeæ”Ð.l
}DÃÒ¹\ñÈ¾(+ƒo‰ä}$oå¾ýòÝW|ÿf/¦­ÑêJ8ë–Ý2TWqm¥”i¶Wžg’âD­åˆÆ²ýl}á£·az0?¢.™Åí™Û·ob<çG¨Û÷…¥Å¯åÆÛÐFh¸áL\çD;>Asg2Èƒ¿yî‚æ×7ƒÚÕYý¹_ÜŸ9ß=Yu•ªn\Ò6’5ŸkKô© ÷]l–;‡>
_ík,ò„Qé=‡Ô-•ÀÑÖ]aŒd¢.–ŽOQ™Ý‹ 4Z_ßs°—Ë)Ô°/™±ÊIÇ¿?ù  `Ï”aÃÓˆi&?»dŽäM€`=‘Ò_7zçuŒÅ4¾I^³uÙ‰ýtXŽZ
—ÊNÌQl^ÝŽà_ÖÉé¡û¢fN©áC˜ ó_¿`!2<)Xý™†9³q'y}Sk4v8 ~l}Ð?É[œÖGŽm@ø‹åð¬5‹ëå9J!
¶þ¬½> ã²‰Áµâ1pˆú*/¥öÁ!èœ€te~cz&ÀëÒ/ù,qÚU
îdõ_Xþyú¿
ÿ
g° ?ï¿çùÐHY›J¿c__e
°k3ç(ˆÄ ×­åæ¦4ä¶•ŒOZ÷òñz/s™¹±LS¸˜CNÓVê•ä×½BqfÈQð™Ø}ßcåq¡½.åýp­ðïò7€4øqà1iGê
îê×®ëÜQx6
½Ú·ý¢á‹Ù‘ä“Éšö‘²o‹U82]šT<ífö{ç¹u™ß¨kT/ut™¤©º´ÚIRÀÏUG¿T°‚êŠÇ,hóRu?_¾Jõv¸Õ¥ñ,ù0CãbÏ˜]lI‘ŸÒ*ÓüÀl&~W¸û:––âéÙw´×*BË²­›aî§/ñ\~¦ñŸ%Ñ>¹X™SµÞ÷|z~›Ê‡ñ÷²;œ35„2Þ#•ŽöR.íŽ½‡ýlË¡5&u›’Ô³”Ï½y[ÂZ—šê D þÒç«8YþáÏß© Ä§ƒ•Ò{È-¶ˆ@²‰û«ö_b+¸’+´!z7}«í/FnÜÏ÷»„f!•d#Ù¦,í£Eâ†Lê #kJ.WßD¿À\f*)c8Ú÷PÀ—´±¨Sj¾ÐIÃïÍ¤­‹’´÷“’â    "BGxê²N…$T2U‚SFëï.2¨Ïõö›\TÚPvL~1¯ ¸ia.Çÿ“·ðe3àÐ!¼ðêØ5‘úã5Z$«±L»šqÚPÉ˜J|/®ú)‘°3ŒEzõ>‚Á²XxOÛƒEeLÄ¼Ýðü©¤˜‰Ù—Ô¹¶RéÉîK¯7wQs—&Ú‘aï7~ÑUèd²ÅMqßaÉš¢…>o™Ø¦ô
ùŽÌW )g‘Ô”Af&F;…[z>ï`mn~çˆÖ³œ‡[]”4#²ŽZh¨3èk%Nñã#aHï‰ª_ûø”M‘O{÷Ú„µ¨ai‹”®°ñ`%Ð¦ µMwŒÞÈÇ9™]@S’²½1¤Nž¿¸BK‚sXŠy„#¡Á¿-ÿ.Êâ&UžÅ*óšiÅ˜P/    è%Þlc±ly˜V3k=¼h®Ì -5êZDÿ.—ÆheAÉYÆä
¥‡
c[‡¨“&–3'OHm$Ø5wòäWoãrRG†„Mžˆ‰‰:¦ãÛðqš¤‘éŽUË§º ŸçvÑ'“_<¯ª´/'fÜÜ¨æ¨V‹´dÂwÑ%ÞQx{>yòÜ+³óž—õaò8ì“¨xªø¸op¿Íæ£«h e½ƒù&"øÉáM1´RN».˜_„ðe"‹w…P„ÒB-ƒ«“ÄŠ¬ŽØa
Óf*'µþÊû™½¯íq·ÖÒæ
§¥9ÑìIvO}.ù*Ù™'šqÖ$
Ì±ëüawÕ48tñV¾ªCýX¹¿?{kcÿPáÓ­«>bxCÇÊüÙ¨›ŠZf('6Âþ/S—­Ú*Þ–m}BÃö&?Ÿ±¬¹ÔjÝóË&J³¹Ù¼D4½O3Ðþþhw6³yÂÂvÂ`ˆ­±‡Ã´,¯6Õê:ÂHZÂúöü÷ó_{÷e¾$_Õ"m´­ª•š°¬áA&
Y8þLHý§cƒ>4"§ÇÐcí‡PR "”åtB•¦îÌv 2R’’Ë#éÓMùŽ‰Â3Üìúâº’fæj4/€4
”Ñ!¸ÛŽ_T­¯ý'TNh&o}†pâ>RpDbUñØl›C7ÖËël {Íd.0ˆÇ‡‚S¬ÂHG¯x}õÚ>¡¾îÓ¹®þ®ò J¡~‰'»þ„Û‰h§~—"J3OÛÙ£›(°IGõÏK~cÍ¿îfã×Å6?3Pïu
ŽóÆGÔÿÀÙ´®žDæš-,Šž~>÷¸IÙ;ôxôâ¹õö®Gü& C+`3m{e‡zBrÇüö¸ñÕ¤õ0ýs\ü3wñy,ÖüZÙÀQ3ÇCþL:‰øZ,ç±Èƒ 0>H§Œ¨+d?¹,ø¨f_&…›3À·É‹7mÈ.Á½ý!ÃäUúõuìÞ'®cíŸÑüo÷¿É8üÖ)ù‘_iþ^¾¾Gè…B¤«Á.ŸoÜ[æÒSGñšÅå«_²äû
¾<ŸWÊÒ
)p ðPo²ºgöÕc†µ].{ò¨¸;>§v,évfšÀ„<‚9/³‚õ ´–M'Í“ÛÉgÜ¯›ýrõŠ*}áÆ«#Ô;(4N/¥öeo)"g(3p?^LƒÄžÙ›N/jáèo™ðAnžN¡RöƒÙ¤«
®­çz©Ý1.©®9ƒ =“D¼owÐ¬)GGG˜²Jè0I? ?c¢–,ú{qƒÿVù…þÃa7ÍØ9[
?|õ7Éy†ÒŒß±ÔŠ­]i’m*e1‹:ÉGpA·‘ñáø1p_ùƒz,ëó)aÿgë›DtâîÙÙ÷Ço¤È¾µ¸N½m÷;§§bx(‹ëñÝg.“úHÌFò'¢f:ø¨koÜæP8°0%—¥­nó ’Ÿàó±*Iu€Y!fßs} í°©ßîg7`Ã 6å”Èq "\ûÞ’¡ j
½
è;§(51ñÒP" -ÀU—Ó]   Uàá³åŽ¶PÅ{'Zy|WøRzå0-¹ƒkÅ‰‡
±â€Ùî*ÊgížÔIÄ+ôÎ#wªž{Ž…3%°õÁ¨}qdDh×ª«²[?Š˜ÛÎH:Óˆ/   ]{çök¯ez¡œÄQ‰=,Ä½ÈÒ}ÛŽ¤ª?.sý”DžIs«,*EŸtŽ »îÜ…Ld@-   6¢0Æp¤4]ýØÄÞ¶³{(%/°ì¢I!Tz`Ò(§OòräçKOˆ JˆÆD#·$¨ûQ½JO/¤‘ ¦.ò$RêwižÔøô¾™ ßä «»ZÙÃø-h1™QÊåÒ×òÎVQù¹`ic_H%‘l¾@x­xTx-ŠMó±4ö
˜ûÔ$À¶ëg“Ýù9ÌVJîô6coîžõÔ‡>O¶É%5U‘Øc}mÊaµ&–ŽYO©É¥„…|…fFâHp5rCºq™,pýUõ(ë6yõL«°è´ÊHãB{¡NïÏñg@OÍ´Ë
ŽIr"w‡jŒ³òÇËà¸¯²oŒþA¼S#„ïß«ñ­Žªú&¿ýNÿ[ÈsÿÌ…Í¦¥ÖÎêD¬P™¥ÄÏÊê÷¤2ømO´¢€B×5«„­ëíÑó”¼ùñd×A¬Ð3õ¹“æ¸ þºY—ÚLÂÙñãM•÷AËG!•àcËdW>ŽHA–fè‹L¦Ÿ($Ó¾eâÙ¨>»,FÏ†;ñí0á$"Xøb^b‰¹ñ¬éx›Ù±§§ŽÖ,CyB8 ª|>ìt`2Jh(í#¿–Ä ‹}úŽŽdnœ<ü¤œ‰ÚBËuÈÿ#‡ñSd_ID¬àÎƒ]ûAi
ZÃ7¥oV
^.3ÍXÃª–lïŠ8:Ì ‰ª¡©æI?ªM
ñx÷—±S¯^
¯|L–®Ë9yŒc‡Ñ[rð@%BŒè±3§ïnÙ¬\qiñ¯Ã%r[YwªÝöÑÆy^,?ýÒªöJ“î&*LôÎù¬KFh)v;)<ñÒ}ÁA¾-¤wòBÖ“6-¾ ÍÏ~·é«þK¬ó~Í)ß6R
ôž‹£¤x÷ûÀ×þ#¿ffOõ·ØxÂ   2‡¹"ò_ž³‰áøýÃ^ÿýšÍ'ôöúCªªó‚~Äñ#‰{9Ø3vPê^Ä‡`Lª@¥ó“Š©êÍ×1”’
R“ÝäÇöµÙºÎœ÷õ¾¢÷ÍcÆ
N\’™É[ÿ€–üVRk3íuÇ ÜÁ‚w§Øu±¹iQ¯B,B´æ-£T„ZCAÒ#ò©‹Q²¯ÒŠÅmHÞŸÉß%NO¶1-¥øWœúD—­Û©ãÅï[?ÞÜ¸êêl™4O’q@?‚º Öõ"Ñw0ÆS°Ë(–ÚóÕÜ·ÑxhfæbZtþ"$d7ÄítN§Á
y"^tÂWÑR”rÞ£ßY%É¾
@­Ðu°7(fÙÔla,;ÛA^×n nP"½¸v³n³c<Ah×²
ƒ
%—›9¼eæ»}t»~8öò@voí[«*ÚZ    3ð.Ú~+Ä€ÞÑ²¯ïbØJœ(
Äc¨f¯¾žÈMºÏÆï/óëð#På5µh-·MCÌ^Yå¿vk‹^¼éc©(dIr{EêÒÀ9›T9þÔ€Žs›'í6¨ˆGòCà¢âƒG!)ÑžUÁÓOzQMÇ
"—‰×î `'jÑ
æŸ-^tÞ­‡Z*² uºg„TË¬’Ny·Í“¥åÆEêÚMò_eÈŒHßÝÿƒNÿ^¡xAÿ¡B¥ŽÆgƒˆÃ¯Åú–u²œ¨ïnÑEEJt?ÛñrµV*FF—u'Â o¯Bð­;q§IÈ/h^å¹¯ýÒå‰-ÂWæ©~ë¨3]è–ËšöjÎ7å(ci÷IÂ/K¯¶kß²iÊôäEiª1õRcÊ±1–[†.û‘--õÛÅ!õç'*â"ÞVe‹ŸˆÚai±ÇCéxC·wð3ßœ:Oí
è›
(†F[nýX"~¢áwéðšy¼0ÊMCÓ©˜]ùgÆç@äý{›ÆÈÑWúºÂÀv°žœ]7œõÜ"¾ïT'u~h2”­—ìî-‘`å6X/\U·”öû8@°ÚJµzºU\éÈöYrµ,ÖY½fG\smÖùT{Àôæ@¶ƒºã†uEtjcéûþvÏimI®D¢é"æéš|æØe˜ˆAßøPÈÞ€€<Ï)O ôWêá¶
ÿ`¿"Âa~sH7%5"9ãI=ù°À‚³'à²¨ƒn@‚'÷[‡–~þØ[.ˆŒ–m°ª'ó¬Ÿ£D7–·´EÚ|Sn”g$ºï×Z£Ñ^‰ÙÜö]õ=Y±8É9éþ{ÙQ×»ƒ]W¼·‹ül}lÌ©¦ì©o|ƒµ¢â4±žZÜ^‚#•Ó´ìq™j+yó
wó×¹ãA€¥}ý_xm$?Ñ^œcõ|yDzwPkõªú‡® Hà?vù”Ýñ Ž°^6Ú¹×r5ä¦Põ§ðëš tÒ7}'gÁ54;@²«_
2îéyÀ<Æ„žÚÃ–Ÿ‚v<0·!f›ìAë›Wx}L'êûõwŽ÷«;K·õ—
U(TAóåyÆ¡Æ‡ó×iÄ1TÛÄ.H“W¡ªÍÙ ¡N0ö›€éZ|2ŒÀKŒüaéh+¸îx±ç«h»WÓWñAw¡¾$G’Y†CÜp…eä¥Ðgžó¡àˆ°£#±ô¯¼Þ™è6ÍV³wÜ/DÇÛ'{Ü´¾Ô–ÒUiWìT<ºÎÇ×}£Eˆ.{¶˜º¤-KVÏö½?   ™Á¼™†OøWãÏ„Æ¬µó~ÖÓ½„›Pvµ«žªóÛxgû£1ÌRÕ
öŠÎ÷)¶ž}`¾6ì†>¶f¶s
oea cTÓûÆÝ·XçØ  o)XmÞé½6$yS sBT’:rcþXÔ- ïÏ…žŠ}É à£Äiûµ\û¸V½82ß“Ÿ7] ÁLh ‡&¾ÓƒIôT**½4ìDÕ#PýPr±[§A6KÇ%†ùÜ 
ƒ
Õha©©¡>r&‹  ïlè;|àÙdC
#É:»O¿ Ó5úHãù-»zŸ(¾ïQÆ‘]JC9*»­$T$¢ôÈ £
â¿yÃÈ”ÈßÎ:ö¼‘GÉµ÷T£ùF7€õ5Þz´ŒE­!{X8Êgì e`S8S„ÝÞêc<CÖ—ßžxV/EÔ+/š4Ùˆ½ht:ëÈr1”¤é ÐP‘@ƒL?ëðvFMë¤û“&˜GßÁä^}ËÄ=©Œû
T¨déqPŠ‡¡`ÿÞ
·¡§?b= PÑ’¼k âšû›RýÂszp©~Z™]ŠŸ¼{r˜Õ—]&Ætß®ÓUiSŽÄTä¾îá1È
7¸‡½S¤X52“¥ºÝçÐõë,<µÒmtMV%pt×Ë]?½¯  q™Cþ5”dó¶¶žÈÌg¦a^S$Â‹À–¬ïõé—U×]º,U8àSŒe ­¾½H;m¢¢¦$öæö2V^K†™Ô.VÕ ±ÙÇÃkå,} …Ž‘ÃõÙA+¾Q·âN…e¯\f¹÷Aìi)Á±[2¨…ò›³b†…
TpP4aózÚ¯d–Ôð×Æ„Z0›5ØÄû÷5GwaeØE-eÛõ “Y&-Ø—P¯ÇØLˆA˜Ã÷@°$çð
zÁp"Ú.^™²Äšâ­ ¯*dïøÍ¥
)Î#œ”o%-²{…YÆ7¸¤9ŽëùÁfkaüpi·2«ÐÑ°K÷&Ÿ~D%¸1+õÜ÷WåhŒí2ÚaÓ)¬´†–#»9ä\J·ÑhlJÖôœjÃK&w)WT¬±¯)±xŒÆþBuiÃ‡É)qTÁÊ~EÄ`€ö÷„ùûEK€_ð?t!õT‰ÀøíÇ5µÍLÔ. Ÿè–‰Q”8)º^èâ#ë6’ˆw®ÚÜ¿sHSýRÖ®#3ãõ`òõºŸ÷Ê5å Ó*”óâNyñÞ™ønžo'CÞz„bæ½¿mé.+™üP²C#þã­î¬$g{¥^@¶œkQ€¸ÊGçGmÙ5bjžê…iø½È-<lRÂå§ãä÷.qN]g_QûB¾õ0Ó~\Èõž©Jïl]•žZÈ
ä~Ú¿´ýõÐ§m±4‡Ñ(
PõAåjë$x
*¤ú’7f‡ìŒâ(ï¢š@QmŽaI“góø1¦xGÇÎÈÍP7õþ(’þ˜%Ï…ËNuƒ')k»<˜ç’FˆR÷<Ïš%X|“ÃHpÃ.=T4ðôévwTÀ?F¯xáu•~u§Óµ ë˜xe~n¨7¸‡Ô¬qLú(Á¨¯ ÖŒl«ú±lÓYkÊNu08ò
/‡’°¤IŠ±-g0
½XtAD
Ú
Sañ™<9œ›·´çÝ¯›;°]&R¹
â‹²à^ÔŒ®eD/qˆM¦lºbuSN~Ù›¨ÕÌÛ‹Üð~Ìl-­Ü‡62 s«‹èxŒØÚ”ÍU0cå`°
9M«ìÄÖ«ŸÇêŸoí¤Çþ^</þŒ   ¡!(")@þþ¿WFÑ‰ƒRf>!Ò•£ãÜ`(iã”¡¾*§h]_ýžI j4x2rE.úZkTÿÝ4PA?­j9ÉžŽ!èìlLñ^é5øÁ1þVºA$§•m#¤ðôbµ«÷ËÕˆAè†SHdªLÉAI-#ØŽ;Šb×õf]!—c ÁÉ×T@D¯n1µ"«24Q-jáÔý“àSçot
ÕßEÍ÷/¢ÖñuóÈš{˜;8Ûðh˜ÛÀÝÞjñ¨{z8 œþ˜¼ ¿l5sÇ?ß_†„Ä‡‚üO(Ù?sx œ  `ƒŠ@@^/àC8Aü¬ +;†›³•§%Ü
¡÷ñÐ¶5wsðÁ@€…/ ¬Ãk ÃÎ£ƒðp€³Áœþ0ædî Ð‘VeçQu¶ú÷ÿšÞÙÍÀÜÒáøÇ ò‚@@0‚ÙÿgÑ‚ÿëóÕ-ì´=ÿ?ß‚¼ÿtáQð‚ÿŒ»¹{  ¼¼ÿ‚ûhÚKçqÄÓp‹Ðh€Î•°¼Bgxn¢iª•¨u²`‹¯Ï¤søuÕžZ[·é%ŽÓØðé9­èUW²ŒRÔ~¢¢V'†&kµ"g
sS®FI
&”0EJ>¢K¯S¾–ƒ¾ÀÜS   Ã53‚)?_ˆ5©[IšpS‡    &ÃJ(#Z†¢PÊsÙbÀT+<•*ïö—Š$ôD¦(yø,R#C
Œ&ý¶ÎC…ðLIYKšTrî>ìËW•²LuÕw^ež‡N_RÞ"‘-¶.){†Q>Rí ¹^^l{:Çÿ!g\¾¥4<•÷57›?ú¹ëXêþ·ƒ2ÊZµz¹*ç\N‹Cö^ª†ö
GŸÕÕé´¾ïéüCÎæ°Å®¸ 7-yN‚©“ßµ
 Û}Ô¥æò3£hmæE47 Ê\Öï¯éªO#ñi¦ óD›ëùsd:w¡~¯\òçˆ§,z§¾{*×ÌWF
·ŒaË«”#*¸òP¯æ›ª|Â¶p¯v©šÞçsÞYYo…gpCkð#‰WU-If¬š¹ž8F<+š½àœÎÌd½~ÕtÒÄÑ6¦WÕ®@~½=ðŸ/7B
ÜÔé]äzÈ’»b}?PÚÈæ];IY¹ÒßO5WMOð¸–yi_*
mg‘w&J  ìå<Øó¿³»=ÍªÀÓÜg‚ÌìšÛøÔÑÒÖDòŒþðåïÂeÛÇ{çpaÕBt3FîýÙÐ9H¿l½*é5ÁÑŽ¶v®×!ç\¤…Õ€¯ëxÇV\s{dÇ»P"s(¥üLóªðJ»G­ÿ˜¾eL¯Îë©1¸pì&wn'Àä¶Z&ö’~Uxðël9$@°Š4˜÷{Ý]ü‰E–þ9µ´÷W(%úÐ2(‡õ¹÷€G.Ö÷´¯æÚQæØtHB„ wéå´/lÍ)[­·'»Êš†xøôÜúDó¹ã_z=úÆ`  yÉs²vþÓòù+Oh9;{ þÊ0Zÿ.-¸õ+¸1ÀÇ÷òŸàRù¯³<X˜Gá ÿãÆƒŒÅ,!¼–ÂÂæüBÖ ak
sk†ƒ,-ø,øàVb °€°…DPXÈÊÂ ¶²óò‚¬­á|¼V‚ð? ¾üT™Ç>‘„JC'%_3°Uc0´ÚÒ]Xb{™Y4ZE Ußcù®g*e¾ó
Å@³1<Éâ5Õz¼Ö    nwãW¯‘Y?jÐ¸;3ª¸óyGélÊY–ÁïÂB^.~F‹
ê$ ºèÞKê+ï¡Î¼ðþû?t÷0wóðqƒ[c øy±˜™åÔå±þPK     à6vV™žÃ+  ×  
                 TESTDOC.XMLPK     à6vVLè×»  Î                D  INTERNAL_TAM.PDFPK      w   -     
----MIME_boundary--
```

i extracted that binary data from given file

```
"""
PK\x03\x04\x14   \x08 à6vV™žÃ+\e\x01  ×\x01  
   TESTDOC.XML]Q]kƒ@\x10|n¡ÿázïÆ¯\x06BÐ\x06ñ\x03\x04s'ñ
-!ÈU¯EðÎ ghÿ}OÅämw˜Ùuv?¼\x06\x17ÖvU#\h®\f\x08˜(š²\x12ß.|#‘¶»×§GçÝóI€}U\x0206($yŒ"\fdKEG
©\x04âÒ…†±I×i\x06G¦âú\x18‘\x03Nò\x14ÇˆdWô\x1E ¤üìBË°lÍ°5Ë"Æzûbnm\x13\x02ù{f.ôûN6\x1C”MÑs&$hYÁª
+!øªj&(W\x1C¥\x14\x1E—äÄÛ¯Ò š—\x18
\x11&áàÿ êç£\x1FxÄ;ÆB²VÐ\x1A\x10ÊO§%[Ÿés\x7F³ï|Ü-:Ñ\x1D}\x19Ï\x04yÁ~\x1E!\x1Fi˜á(ÁÙB} '\f\x145­8êù'kÕÑH¥¡BQ±@ýßô^ÂÑ'ýÉyøÒ\x1FPK\x03\x04\x14   \x08 à6vV\x1ALè×»\x1E  Î   \x10   INTERNAL_TAM.PDF…˜uT\Û²¯\x03Á!¸kãÞt7îÖHãî!X\x03»K€à\x04\x0F\x1Aœà\x01\x02Á\x03Á5x ¸\x06
î\x04}yûÝwï\x19wïqÎ\x7F«æªQs®5\x7F_ÕœÅ¬\x01•ç\x06\x03ù±˜76Ç§±ø\x01 €³…\x1D–˜\x18
ÜÉÆÃ\x16 \f\x12â‘G8xÀÝxä\x1DÌ=àP¸¥³\x15\BÂÝÃ
nîˆåó>'ÝØyA‘x`õ}ÛœN
ÁûmÙ2W)å@€ð­V¾–~ŒN‹µ’Éo\x19G¢,çU^´…ƒ\x18Þ+=E³ç;;O-·7Æ\x17Ö$`BÖÐªY—ÎûŸ<0¡€SæÖµ\x1A½Wê¯V«
¯'›\x1Eã’úV Â¬‰Àv©ÌwQ¼0þè\x0Fù*‰)’\x1D_\x02î.êê~\x7F^Ü\x1FÅŸ˜X\x08t\x10u\x1Cë\x15ï]¶kn‰\x02\\eÚú?–¢“Pñ¬£†ÄfœÑ÷V¹¬NÛå\x08ü¬P<?\x13ƒ±€ÙðÂV\x0E\x16¾¸9ÆFi\x0Ek0¢‘ã‘éíGêC{\x0F¦lG\x08ˆëÅ9\x1Aù¤5÷§^(b.$¼ë.Óí%§9ù5LÒW­˜$,Ýo Üš^ÔÉ\e^à\x04\x1CáãAëEÁDÜíRÞ6Û/òÕ˜:ÿ
\\x11·öÜ´ÕcD%¶çà‚Š\x15ˆô—]«¶{ª^‹iŒJË3d28¦èg ¾¬\x19ú‚Õ\x13W€\x13Îmãýãé\x1E&Q\x15¥Ë•´\x03»ZË$Õ9_-ëKIÌ\x7FxºTbI-¨Õ4¥k¡èÓ)Ð\x18Ç®s1\x16Y3Nœjid4L°[\x12\x10

}Ÿ´É:èÓœ¨$“Â^\x0E\W¤oàbŸ†ÊÂ6i¦\x06X>¶ºXuÇe\x1ECÎ®&àQÄ\x19\x12¯5\x17î"\x1Aü\x17CR«ûûÇaÊø\x10\teó±f®pŠÍ:\x14Œ]¤Qfq4\x03 j@\x13§¤(ŸÉô\Gïû¡Ëeæ”Ð.l\x04
}DÃÒ\x0F¹\ñÈ¾(+ƒo\x0F‰ä}$oå\f¾ýòÝW|\x08ÿf/¦­ÑêJ8ë–Ý2TWqm\x10\x1A¥”\x11i¶Wžg’âD­åˆÆ²ýl}á£·az0\x10?¢.™Åí™Û·ob<çG¨Û÷…¥Å¯åÆÛÐFh¸\x02áL\çD;>Asg2Èƒ¿yî‚æ×7\x0F\x03ƒÚÕYý¹_ÜŸ9ß=Yu•\x12ªn\Ò6’5Ÿ\x02\fkKô© ÷]l–;‡\x0F>
_ík,ò„Qé\x08=\x01‡Ô-\x15•ÀÑÖ\x02]aŒd¢.–ŽOQ™Ý‹ 4\eZ_ßs°—Ë)\x18Ô°/™±ÊIÇ¿?ù\t`Ï”a\x01ÃÓˆi\x13&?»dŽäM€`=‘Ò_7zçuŒÅ4¾I^³uÙ\x1A\x10‰ýtXŽZ
—ÊN\x18ÌQl^ÝŽà_ÖÉé¡û¢fN©á\x11C˜ \x11ó\x06_¿`!2\x18<)Xý™\x19†9³q'\x0Fy}Sk4v8 ~l}Ð?É[\x15œÖGŽm@ø‹åð¬5‹ëå9J!
¶þ¬½> ã²‰\x01Áµâ1pˆú*/¥öÁ!èœ€te~cz&Àë\x0EÒ/ù,qÚU\x1C
îdõ_Xþyú¿\x18
ÿ
g° ?ï¿çùÐHY›J\x01¿c__e
\x7F°k3ç\x1A(ˆÄ ×­\x1Dåæ¦4ä\x13¶•ŒOZ÷òñz/s™\x04¹±LS¸˜CNÓVê•ä×½B\x1EqfÈ\x1FQð\e™Ø}ßcåq¡½\x06.åýp­ðïò7€4øqà1iGê
îê×®ëÜQx\x126
½Ú·ý¢á\x1C\x1C‹Ù‘ä“Éšö‘²o‹U82]šT<í\x16fö{ç¹u™ß¨kT\f/ut\x03™¤©º\x7F´ÚIRÀ\e\x18ÏUG¿T°‚\x7FêŠÇ,\x04hóRu?_¾\x1AJ\x0Fõv¸Õ¥ñ,ù0CãbÏ˜]lI‘ŸÒ\x1F*ÓüÀ\x0Fl&~W¸û:––âéÙw´×*BË²­›\x05aî§/ñ\\x0F~¦ñŸ%Ñ>¹X™SµÞ÷|z~\x1A›Ê‡ñ\x01÷²\x1C;œ35\x14„2Þ#•ŽöR.í\fŽ½‡ýlË¡5&u›’Ô³”Ï½y[ÂZ—šê D þ\x17Òç«8YþáÏß©\x1A Ä§ƒ\x1C•Ò{\x13È-¶ˆ@²‰û«ö_b\x19+¸’+´!z7}«í/\x1FFnÜÏ÷»„f!•d#Ù¦,í£Eâ†Lê #kJ.WßD¿À\f*)c8Ú÷PÀ—´±¨Sj¾ÐIÃïÍ¤­‹’´÷“’â \t"BGxê\x1C²N…$T2U‚SFëï.2¨Ïõö›\\x06TÚPvL~\x121¯ ¸i\x1Fa.Çÿ\x18“·ðe3àÐ!¼ðêØ5‘\x03úã5Z$«±L\e»š\x04qÚPÉ˜J|/®ú\x01)\x1A‘°3ŒEzõ>‚Á²X\x1Dx\x18O\x1AÛ\x12ƒEeLÄ¼Ýðü©¤˜‰Ù—Ô¹¶Ré\x15ÉîK\x12¯7w\x08Qs—&Ú‘aï7~ÑUèd²ÅM\x1CqßaÉš¢…>o™Ø¦\x16ô
ùŽÌ\x16\x03W )g\x13‘Ô\x13”Af&F;…[z\x19>ï`\x17mn~çˆ\x06Ö³œ\x17\x04‡[]”4#²ŽZh¨\x123èk%Nñã#aHï‰ª_û\x7Fø”M‘O{÷Ú„µ\f¨ai‹”®°ñ`%Ð¦ µMw\x18ŒÞÈÇ9™\x12]@S’²\f½1¤Nž¿¸BK‚sXŠy„#\x13¡Á¿\x19-\x12\x06ÿ.\x15Êâ&UžÅ*ó\x03šiÅ˜P\x16/\tè%Þl\x16\x11c±ly˜V\x0F3k=¼h®Ì \x16-5\x17êZDÿ.—ÆheAÉYÆä
\x0E¥‡
c[‡¨“&–3'O\x19Hm$Ø\x135\x17wò\x1DäWoãrRG†„Mž\x04ˆ‰‰:¦ãÛðqš¤\x19‘é\x05ŽUË§\x1Fº \x12ŸçvÑ\x1D'\x14“_\x0E<¯ª´/'fÜÜ¨\x08æ¨V‹´dÂwÑ%ÞQx\x13{>yò\fÜ+³óž—õaò8ì“¨xªø¸op¿Íæ£«h e½ƒù\x0F\x14\x04&"øÉáM1´R\x11\x03N».˜_„\x1Aðe"‹w\x1D…P„ÒB-ƒ«“Ä\fŠ\x03¬ŽØa
Óf*'µþ\x1DÊû\x1C™½¯íq·ÖÒæ
§¥9Ñì\fIvO}.ù*Ù™'šqÖ$\x14
Ì±\x13ëüawÕ48tñV¾ªCýX\x1F¹¿?{kcÿPáÓ­«>\x03bxCÇÊüÙ¨›Š\x1CZ\x0Ff(\x10'6Âþ/S\e\x08—\x1C­Ú*Þ–m}BÃö&?\x01Ÿ±¬¹\x1CÔj\x1EÝóË&J³¹Ù¼D4½O3Ðþþhw6³yÂÂvÂ\x14`ˆ­±‡\x13\x16\x19\x1AÃ´,¯6Õê:ÂHZÂúöü÷ó\x13_\x7F\x06{\x1E÷\x18e¾$\x18_Õ"m´­ª•š°¬\x15á\x18A&
Y8\x17þ\x16\x7F\x12LHý§cƒ>4"§ÇÐcí‡PR "”åtB•¦îÌv 2R’’Ë#é\eÓMùŽ‰Â3Üì\x12úâ\x1Fº’fæ\x12j4/€4
”Ñ!¸Û\x13\x14Ž_\fT­¯ý'TNh&o}†pâ>RpD\x02bUñØl›C7ÖËël {Íd.0\x12ˆÇ\x0F‡‚S¬ÂHG¯x}õÚ>¡¾îÓ¹®þ®ò J¡\x08~\x16‰'»þ„Û‰h§~\x12—"J3OÛ\x0FÙ£›(°IGõÏ\x12K~cÍ¿\x08îfã\x18×Å6?3Pïu
\x11ŽóÆGÔÿ\x19ÀÙ´®\x01žDæš-,Šž~>÷¸IÙ;ôxô\fâ¹õö®Gü& C+`3m{e‡zBrÇüö¸ñÕ\x14¤õ0ýs\ü\x1D3wñy\x10,ÖüZÙ\x11ÀQ3ÇC\x11þL:‰øZ,ç±Èƒ 0>H§Œ¨+d?¹,ø¨f_&…›3À\x1F·É\x1A‹7mÈ.Á½ý!ÃäUúõuì\x16Þ'®c\x16íŸÑ\x1Aüo÷¿É8\x06üÖ)ù‘_iþ^¾¾Gè…B¤«Á.ŸoÜ[æÒSGñšÅå«_²\x0Eä\x15\x1Aû
¾<ŸWÊÒ
)p ðPo²ºgöÕ\x18c†µ]\x11.{\x13ò¨¸;>§v,\eé\x17\x15vfšÀ„<‚9/³‚õ ´\x02–M'Í“ÛÉgÜ¯›ýrõ\x13Š*}áÆ\x1E\f«#Ô;\x06(4N/¥öe\x05o)\f"g(3p?^L\x03ƒÄžÙ›N/jáèo™ðA\x0FnžN¡R\x1FöƒÙ\x14¤\x08«
®­çz©Ý1.©®9ƒ =“D¼owÐ¬)GGG˜²Jè0\x03I? ?c¢–,ú{q\x04ƒÿV\x1Dù…\x04þÃa7ÍØ9[
?|õ7Éy†ÒŒß±ÔŠ­]i’m*e1‹:ÉGpA·\x06‘ñáø1p_ùƒ\x1Fz,ëó)aÿ\fgë\x13›Dtâî\fÙ\x0E\x08Ù÷Ço¤È\x19¾µ¸N½m÷;§§bx\x1D(‹ëñÝg.“úHÌFò'¢f:ø¨\x05koÜæP8°0%—\x05¥­\x7Fnó\t\f’Ÿàó±*Iu€Y!fßs} í°©ßîg7`Ã 6å”Èq "\ûÞ’¡\x01 \x15j
½
è;§(51ñÒP" -ÀU—Ó]\tUàá³åŽ¶P\eÅ{'Zy|WøRzå0\x06-¹ƒkÅ‰‡
\x01\x1F±â€Ùî*\x13ÊgížÔIÄ+ôÎ#wªž{\x19Ž…3\x18%\x18°õÁ¨}qdDh×ª«²[?Š˜ÛÎH:Óˆ/\t]\x15{çök¯ez¡œÄQ‰=,Ä½ÈÒ}ÛŽ¤ª?.sý”DžIs«,*EŸtŽ »îÜ…Ld@-\t6¢0Æ\x1Dp¤4]ýØÄÞ\x05¶³{\x7F(%/°ì¢I!Tz`Ò(§OòräçKOˆ JˆÆD#·$¨ûQ½JO\x11/¤‘ ¦.\x13ò$RêwižÔøô¾™\x13 ßä «»ZÙÃø-\x13h1™QÊåÒ×òÎVQù¹`\x17ic_H%‘l¾@x­x\x08Tx-ŠMó±\x034\x1Aö
\x1D˜ûÔ\x02\x1C$À¶ëg“Ýù9ÌVJ\x1Aîô6coîžõÔ‡>O¶É%5U‘Øc}mÊaµ&–ŽYO©É¥„…|…fFâHp5rCºq™,pýUõ(ë6y\x16õL«°è´ÊHãB{¡NïÏñg@OÍ´Ë
ŽIr\x05\x01"w\x1C‡jŒ³òÇËà¸¯\x03²oŒþA¼\x7FS#\x1F„ïß«ñ­Žªú&\x08¿ýNÿ[ÈsÿÌ…Í\x04¦¥ÖÎêD¬P\x01™¥Ä\x19ÏÊê÷¤2ømO´¢\x0F€B×5«„­ëíÑó”¼ùñd×A¬Ð3õ¹“æ¸ \x18þºY—ÚLÂÙñãM•÷AËG!•àcËdW>ŽHA–fè‹L¦Ÿ($Ó¾\x11\x1EeâÙ¨>»,F\x19Ï†;ñí0á$"Xøb^b‰¹ñ¬éx›Ù±§\x17§\x01ŽÖ\x15,Cy\x12\x1AB8\x13 ª|>ìt`2Jh(\x08í#¿–Ä ‹}ú\x11ŽŽdnœ<ü¤œ‰\x11ÚBËu\x17Èÿ#‡ñSd_ID¬àÎƒ]ûAi
Z\x1CÃ7\x1D¥oV
^.3ÍXÃª–\x16lïŠ8:Ì\x18\x08 ‰ª¡\x14©æI\x17?\x17\x04ªM
ñx÷—±S¯^
¯|L–®Ë\x0F\x139yŒc‡Ñ[rð\x1A@%BŒ\x1Aè±3§ïnÙ¬\qiñ\x7F¯Ã%\x1Ar[YwªÝöÑÆ\x04y^,\x19?ýÒª\x1EöJ“î&*LôÎù¬KFh)v;)\x08\x1C<ñÒ}ÁA¾-¤wòBÖ“6-¾ ÍÏ~·é\x04«þK¬ó~Í)\x13ß6R
ôž‹£¤x÷ûÀ×þ#¿ffO\x0Eõ·ØxÂ\t\x022‡¹"ò_ž³‰áøýÃ^ÿýšÍ'ô\x1FöúCªªó‚\x14~Äñ#‰{9\x14Ø3vPê^Ä‡`Lª@¥ó“Š©êÍ×1\x13”’\f
\x1A\x10R“ÝäÇ\x12öµÙºÎœ÷õ¾¢÷ÍcÆ
\x18N\\x1E’™É[ÿ€–üV\x0ERk3\x7FíuÇ ÜÁ‚w§Øu±¹iQ¯B,B´æ-£T„ZCAÒ#ò©‹Q²¯ÒŠÅmHÞŸ\x02Éß%NO¶1-\x0E¥øWœúD—­Û©ãÅï\x1E[?ÞÜ¸êêl™4O’q@?‚\x0Fº Öõ"Ñw0ÆS°Ë(–Ú\x0FóÕ\x19Ü\x15·Ñx\x1ChfæbZtþ"$d7\x11ÄítN§Á
\x18y"^tÂ\x17\x0EWÑR”r\x12Þ£ß\x16Y%É¾
@­\x0FÐu°7(fÙÔla,;ÛA^×n nP"½¸v³n³c<\fAh\x1E\x15×²
ƒ
\x0E%—›9¼eæ»}t»\x0F~8öò@voí[«*ÚZ\t3ð.Ú~\e\x16+Ä€ÞÑ²¯ïbØJœ(
Äc¨f¯¾žÈMºÏÆï/óëð#På5µh-·MCÌ^\x0EYå¿\x14\x1Fvk‹^¼éc\e©\x11(\x1EdI\x0Er{EêÒÀ9›T9þ\x13Ô€Žs›'í6¨ˆGòCà¢âƒ\x1CG!)ÑžU\x03ÁÓOzQMÇ
\x0F"—\x04\x03\x0E‰×\x13î `'jÑ
æŸ\x17-^tÞ­‡Z*² uºg„\x17TË¬’N\x1Ey·Í“¥åÆEêÚMò_e\x1EÈŒHßÝÿƒN\x04ÿ^¡xAÿ¡B¥ŽÆgƒˆÃ¯Åú–u²œ¨ïnÑEE\x17Jt?\x14ÛñrµV*FF—u'Â \x1Fo¯\x1ABð­;q§IÈ/h^å¹¯ýÒå‰-Â\x12Wæ©~\x01ë\x13¨3\x02]è–ËšöjÎ7å(\x03ci÷IÂ/K¯¶kß²iÊôäEiª1õRcÊ±1–[†.û‘-\e-\x1DõÛÅ!õç'*â"\x10ÞVe‹ŸˆÚai±ÇCéxC·\x03wð3ß\x19œ:Oí
è›
(†F\x1C[\x1En\x1EýX"\x03~¢\x16áwéðšy¼0Ê\x1DMCÓ©˜]ùgÆç@äý{›ÆÈÑW\x06úºÂÀ\x1Ev°žœ]7œõÜ"¾ïT'u~h\f2”­—ìî-‘`å6X/\U·”öû8@°ÚJµzº\x02U\éÈö\eYrµ,ÖY\x1C½fG\sm\x1FÖùT{Àôæ@¶ƒºã†\x13uEtjcéûþvÏimI®D¢é"æéš|æØe˜ˆAßøPÈÞ\x14€€<\x06Ï)O ôWêá¶
ÿ`¿"Âa~sH\x1E7%5"9ãI=ù°À‚³'à\x1E²¨ƒn@‚'÷[‡–~þØ[.ˆŒ–m°ª'\x14\x06ó¬\eŸ£D7–·´\x04EÚ|Sn”g$ºï×Z£\x01Ñ^‰\x01ÙÜö]\x1Cõ=Y±8É9éþ\x12{ÙQ×»ƒ]W¼·‹ül}lÌ©¦ì©\x13o|ƒµ¢â4\x1E±žZÜ\x10^‚#•Ó´ìq™j+yó
w\x12ó×\x1D¹ãA€¥}ý_\x01xm$?Ñ^œcõ|yDzwPkõ\x0Fªú‡® Hà?vù”Ý\x19\x04ñ Ž\x03°^6Ú¹×r5ä¦Põ§ðëš\ttÒ7}'gÁ54;@²«_
2îéyÀ<Æ„žÚÃ–Ÿ‚v\e<\x050·!f›ìA\x04ë›Wx}L'êûõwŽ÷«;\x01K·õ—
U(TAóåyÆ¡Æ‡ó×iÄ1TÛÄ.H\x0E“\x15W¡ª\x04\eÍÙ\x0E ¡N0ö\x12›€éZ|2ŒÀKŒüaéh+¸îx±ç«h»WÓWñAw¡¾$\x02G’\x1FY†CÜp…eä¥Ðgžó¡àˆ°\x04£\e#±ô¯¼Þ™è6ÍV³wÜ/DÇÛ'{Ü´¾Ô–ÒUiWìT<ºÎÇ×}£\x1CEˆ.{¶\x18\x10˜º¤-\x12KVÏö½?\t™Á¼™†OøWãÏ„Æ\x1E¬µó~Ö\x17Ó½„›Pvµ«žªóÛxgû\x19\x01£1Ì\x0ERÕ
öŠÎ÷)¶ž}`¾6ì†>¶f¶s
oea cTÓûÆÝ\x1A·XçØ\to)X\x03mÞé½6$yS sBT’:rcþ\eXÔ-\tïÏ\x11…žŠ}\x10É\tà£Äiû\x1Dµ\û¸V½82ß“Ÿ7] ÁL\x01h ‡&¾ÓƒIôT**½4ìDÕ#PýPr±[\x12§A6KÇ%†ùÜ 
ƒ
\x1CÕh\x7Fa©©¡>r&\x12‹\tïlè;|àÙdC
\e#É:»O¿ Ó5ú\x1FH\x1Cãù-»zŸ(¾ïQÆ‘]JC9*»­\x08$\x14T$¢\x1CôÈ \x0F£
â¿yÃÈ”ÈßÎ:ö¼‘G\x06É\x14\x1Dµ÷T\x11£\x11ùF7€õ5Þz´ŒE­!{X8Êgì e`S8S„ÝÞêc<\x1CCÖ—ßžxV/\x10EÔ\x1F+/š4\x12Ùˆ½ht:ëÈr1”¤é\x19 \x05ÐP‘\x1C@\x1AƒL?ë\x12ðvFMë¤\x03û“&˜GßÁä^}ËÄ=©Œû
\x1AT\e¨déqPŠ‡¡`ÿÞ
·\x15¡§?b= PÑ’¼\x14k â\x1Fšû›\x1ARýÂszp©~Z™\x18]ŠŸ¼{r˜Õ—]&Ætß®ÓUiSŽÄTä¾îá1È
7¸‡½S¤\x02X52“¥ºÝçÐõë,<µÒmtMV%pt×Ë]?½¯\tq™Cþ5”dó\x13¶¶žÈÌg¦a^S$Â‹À–¬ïõé—U\f×\x03]º,U8àSŒ\x17e ­¾½H;m¢¢¦$öæö2\x01V^K†™Ô.VÕ\t±ÙÇÃkå,}\x1F …Ž\x1C‘Ãõ\x1FÙA+¾Q·âN…e¯\f¹÷Aìi)Á±[\x0E2¨…ò›³b\x02†…
TpP4aózÚ¯d–Ôð×Æ„\x03Z0›5ØÄû÷5GwaeØE\x0E-eÛõ “Y&-Ø—P¯ÇØLˆA˜Ã÷@°\x08$çð
zÁp"\x11Ú.^\x19™²Ä\ešâ­ ¯*d\x01ïø\x11Í¥
)Î#œ”o%-²{…YÆ7¸\x0F¤9ŽëùÁfkaüpi·\x132«ÐÑ\x13°\x1C\x14K\x1D÷&Ÿ~D%¸1+õÜ÷\x13WåhŒ\x1Cí2Ú\x03a\x03Ó)¬´†–#»9ä\\x08J·ÑhlJÖôœjÃK&w)WT¬±¯)±xŒÆþBuiÃ‡É)q\x12TÁÊ~EÄ`€\x1Cö÷„\x03ùûEK€_ð?t!õT‰ÀøíÇ5µÍLÔ. Ÿ\x06è–‰Q”8)\x19º^èâ#ë6’ˆw®ÚÜ¿sHSýRÖ®#3ãõ`òõºŸ÷Ê\x035å Ó*”\x02óâNyñÞ\x01™ønžo'CÞz\x12„bæ½¿mé.+™üP²C#þã­î\x12¬$g{¥^@¶œkQ€\x03¸ÊGçGmÙ\x025bjžê…iø\x0F½È-<l\x18R\x10Âå§ãä÷.qN]g_QûB¾õ0Ó~\x06\Èõž©Jïl]•žZÈ
ä~Ú¿´ýõ\x1DÐ§\x11m\e±4‡Ñ(
PõAåjë$x
*¤ú’7f‡\x1AìŒâ(ï¢š@QmŽ\x01aI“góø\x1E1¦xG\x1CÇÎÈÍP\x147õþ(\x0E’þ˜%Ï\x18\x1A…\x0EËNuƒ')k»<˜\x10ç’FˆR÷<Ïš%X|“ÃH\x16\x0FpÃ.=T4ðôévwTÀ?\x17F¯xáu•~\x12u§\x15\x05\x0FÓµ ë˜x\x1Ce~n¨7¸‡Ô¬qLú(Á\x10¨\x14¯ ÖŒl\x0E«ú±lÓYkÊNu08ò
/‡’°¤IŠ±-g0
½XtAD
Ú
Sañ™<9œ›·´çÝ¯\x14›;\x14°]&R¹
â‹²à\f^ÔŒ®eD/q\x03ˆM¦lºbuSN~Ù›¨ÕÌÛ‹Üð~Ìl-­Ü‡\x0462 s«‹èxŒØÚ”ÍU0cå`\x10°
9M«ìÄÖ«ŸÇêŸoí¤Çþ^</þŒ\t¡!(")\x15@þþ\x18¿WFÑ‰ƒRf\x1E>!Ò•£ã\x13Ü`(iã”¡¾*§h\x03]\x03_ýžI j4x2r\x16E.úZk\x11TÿÝ4PA?­j9ÉžŽ!\x03èìlLñ^é5øÁ1þVºA$§•m#¤ðôbµ«÷ËÕ\x14ˆAè†SHdªLÉAI-#ØŽ;Š\x06b×õf]\x12!—c ÁÉ×T@D¯n1µ"«24Q-jáÔý“àS\x01çot\x18
ÕßEÍ÷/¢ÖñuóÈš{˜;8Ûðh˜ÛÀÝ\x01\x02\x7FÞjñ¨{z8 œþ˜¼ ¿l5sÇ?\x06ß_†„Ä\x7F‡‚üO(Ù?sx œ \x7F `ƒŠ@@\x10^\x10/\x04\x02\x16à\x03C\x048Aü¬ \x10+;†›³•§%Ü
¡\x03÷ñÐ¶5ws\x01ð\x01Á@\x01€…/ ¬Ãk ÃÎ£ƒðp€³Áœþ0ædî Ð‘VeçQu¶ú÷ÿšÞÙÍÀÜÒ\x03áøÇ\x15 \x11\x02ò‚@@0\x08\x04\x06‚ÙÿgÑ‚ÿëóÕ-ì´=\x1Cÿ?ß‚¼ÿtáQ\x03ð‚ÿŒ»¹{  ¼¼ÿ‚ûhÚKç\x05\x10qÄÓp‹\x03Ðh€Î•°¼Bgxn¢\x15\x17iª•\x1E¨u²`‹¯Ï¤søuÕžZ\x02[·é%ŽÓØðé9­èUW²ŒRÔ~¢¢V'†\x16&kµ"g\x08
s\x01S®F\x05I
\x1F\x19\x01&\x13”0EJ>¢\x16K¯S¾–ƒ¾ÀÜS\tÃ53‚)?_ˆ5©[IšpS‡\t&Ã\x1AJ(#\x16Z†¢PÊ\x0EsÙ\x10bÀT+<•\x10*ïö—Š$ôD¦(yø,R#C
Œ&ý¶ÎC…ðLIYK\x11šTrî>\eìËW•²LuÕ\x17w^ež‡N_R\x03Þ\x12"‘-¶.){†Q>Rí ¹^^l{:Çÿ!g\¾\x04¥4<•÷5\e7›?ú¹ëX\x1Fêþ·ƒ2\e\x0EÊZµz¹*ç\N‹Cö^ª†ö
G\x7FŸÕÕ\x1Fé´¾ïéüCÎæ°Å®¸ 7-yN‚©“ßµ
\x05 Û}Ô¥\x08æò3£hm\x1CæE47 Ê\Ö\x04ï\x0E¯éªO#ñi¦ óD›ë\x1Dùsd:w¡~¯\ò\x12çˆ§,\x08z§¾{*×ÌWF
·ŒaË\x1E\x0E«”#*¸òP\x0E\x08¯æ\x14\x16›ª|\x19Â¶\x14\fp¯v©šÞ\x18çsÞYYo…gpCkð#‰\x7FWU-If¬š¹\x0Fž8F<+š½àœÎÌd½~ÕtÒÄÑ6¦WÕ\x13®@\x15~½=\x10ðŸ/7B
ÜÔé]äzÈ’»b}\x19?PÚÈæ];IY¹ÒßO5WM\x01Oð¸–yi_*
mg‘w&J\tìå<Øó¿³»=ÍªÀÓÜg\x7F‚ÌìšÛøÔÑÒÖDòŒþðåïÂeÛÇ{ç\x10paÕBt3FîýÙÐ9H¿\x05l½*é5ÁÑŽ¶v®×!\x1Fç\¤…Õ€¯ëxÇV\x1F\s{dÇ»P"s(¥üLóª\x06ðJ»G­ÿ˜¾eL¯Îë©1¸pì&\x13wn'Àä¶Z&ö’~Uxð\x1Aël9$@\x12°Š4˜÷{Ý]ü‰E–þ9µ´÷W(%úÐ2(‡õ¹÷€G.Ö\x12÷´¯æÚQæØtH\eB„ wéå´/lÍ)[­·'»\x04Êš†xø\x14ôÜ\x19úDó\x0F¹ã_z=úÆ` \x04 yÉ\x03s²vþÓòù+Oh9;{ þÊ0Zÿ.\x03-¸õ\x1F\x0F+¸1\x08ÀÇ÷òŸàRù¯³<X˜G\eá ÿãÆ\x03ƒ\x02ŒÅ,!¼–\x02ÂÂ\x16æ\x16üBÖ ak
sk\x08\x18\x0E†ƒ,-ø,øàV\x12b °€°…\x15DPXÈÊ\x1CÂ ¶²\x06óò‚¬­á|¼V\x02‚ð? ¾ü\x17T™Ç>‘„J\x11C'%_3°Uc0´ÚÒ]Xb{™Y\x104Z\x13E U\x1Eßc\x1Eù®g\x18*e¾ó
Å@³1<Éâ\e5Õz¼\x1AÖ\tnwãW¯‘Y?jÐ¸;3ª¸óyGélÊY–\x1FÁï\x1FÂB^\x10.~\x1FF‹
ê$ ºèÞKê\x06+ï¡\x13Î¼ðþû?t÷0wóðqƒ[c\tøy±˜™åÔå±þ\x0FPK\x01\x02\x14 \x14   \x08 à6vV™žÃ+\e\x01  ×\x01  
                 TESTDOC.XMLPK\x01\x02\x14 \x14   \x08 à6vV\x1ALè×»\x1E  Î   \x10             D\x01  INTERNAL_TAM.PDFPK\x05\x06    \x02 \x02 w   -     
"""
```

when i put into file_put_contents('TEST.ZIP', $data), it creates an invalid zip file. **any help will be appreciated**

Comment: You can't cut and paste binary data. How did you put it in $data? I suggest you try to get the API to send it to you as base64 then you can use base64_decode().

Comment: Basically, I read the complete file and get binary data content ,this content use as a $data for creating a file, and it's coming from webhook so i have no choice to get as base64

Comment: What exactly is _"i extracted that binary data from given file"_ supposed to mean? Are you saying you did this manually? Or by applying some string functions/regex to what you received ...?

Comment: This looks like a mix of a multipart/formdata request, and a multipart email body. If it was the former with an actual "file upload", then it should say `Content-Disposition: form-data`, so I am guessing you will probably not be able to access this via $_FILES (just a guess though, give it a try to make sure) - and you might need a multipart email parser instead.

Comment: I'm applying both strategies but didn't work and it is the **MTOM** file format so the Content-Disposition must be an attachment

Comment: after some working I realize that binary data is corrupted, like when we open the image on notepad and save  the image again, the image will break because notepad is a plain text editor and this data is something like that. So any idea how we restore the binary data